# jQuery 1.6.2 mouseup not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.6

This code runs well with jQuery-1.3.2.min.js but doesn't run with jQuery-1.6.2.min.js .

```
$(function(){
    $(document).mousedown(mouseUpAfterDrag);

function mouseUpAfterDrag(e) {

    /* You can record the starting position with */
    var start_x = e.pageX;
    var start_y = e.pageY;

    $().mousemove(function(e) {
        /* And you can get the distance moved by */
        var offset_x = e.pageX - start_x;
        var offset_y = e.pageY - start_y;
    });

    $().one('mouseup', function() {
        alert("This will show after mousemove and mouse released.");
        $().unbind();
        $(document).mousedown(mouseUpAfterDrag);
    });

    // Using return false prevents browser's default,
    // often unwanted mousemove actions (drag & drop)
    return false;
    }
});
```

how to make this code work on jQuery-1.6.2.min.js?
any solution?

Comment: Any error messages? Try using firebug.

Comment: By "doesn't run" you mean what, exactly?

Comment: @mblase75 mouseup is not firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you wanted to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/qtU4H/

```
var start_x, start_y, offset_x, offset_y;

$(document).mousedown(function(e) { 
    start_x = e.pageX;
    start_y = e.pageY;
    // console.log("start = " + start_x + "," + start_y);
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!isNaN(start_x)) {
        offset_x = e.pageX - start_x;
        offset_y = e.pageY - start_y;
        // console.log("offset = " + offset_x + "," + offset_y);
    }
}).one('mouseup', function() {
    alert("This will show after mousemove and mouse released.");
});
```

Comment: mouseup is working only once, when i click second time it won't work at all.

Comment: @Raju Yes, that's what the `.one` method is supposed to do. If you don't want that, use `.mouseup(function() ...)` instead.

Comment: mousemove is running every time.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but I'm simply not clear on what you want the script to do.

Comment: And then what? After the mouseup, stop tracking anything?

Comment: ThanQ so much.. :)
it's working fine..
And I'm so sorry to bug with my bad english..